# ActionListener acting wierd

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am having a problem with my `ActionListener`'s not acting as (I think) they should. I have the below code:

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             final String text = textField.getText();
             if (text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").contains("whats new")){
                 textArea.setText("Oh, you know...work...college. I am a computer science major and software engineer.\nDo you program?");
                 if (text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").contains("yes")){
                     textArea.setText("Cool!");
                 }else{
                     textArea.setText(":(");
                 }
             }
          }
        });
```

The `textField` is where the user types the question, and the `textArea` is where the program answers.
The problem is, when I type "whats new", then "yes", it gives me the default string I set for when it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not thinking fourth-dimensionally! (kidding aside now)

You are attempting to handle the sequence of events at once in your listener but your listener will actually be called multiple times: once for an answer to the first question and a second time for a reply to your follow-up comment.

You need to make your listener handle both of these states independently. You probably need to capture the state of your last asked question in the class scope and check it in your listener to determine what question was asked so you will know how to evaluate the contents of `text` and give the proper reply.

You will probably not study finite automata or formal study of state machines for several more semesters, but it's a crucial step to have elementary understanding of. Without knowing the problem statement provided, I assume the assignment is trying to push you into that direction. Also, in any paradigm, though for Java we'll stick with OO, there are many ways to add some layers of beauty and fault-tolerance for a better solution, but my intent is to stick with what is simplest for you. For example, you could make a class that represents each state pending the user's response (question 1, question 2, etc.) and model the states and transitions within your application. Each state as modeled would know of the question asked, potential answers, and transitions to other states. In an OO system, each of these states would have an API and operate via some call like `execute()` which would evaluate the current state of the system and determine a transition. Do some more research on this on your own.

Back to your simpler example. Let's say you only have two cases, one for each question: "what's new" and "do you program". Store some representation in your class (named constants are good practice):

```
class Interrogator {
     String q1 = "what's new";
     String a1 = ...do you program?";
     String q2 = "yes";
     ...
}
```

Now in your `actionPerformed`, test the contents of *both* your question-text-area against known questions and your answer area against known responses: `if (a1.equals(textArea.getText() && q2.equals(text.getText()))` then you know you the answer to the initial (unprompted) question is displayed and an expected response was entered. Don't forget your formatting translation (to lower case, strip quotes).

Comment: I'm reluctant to give a good working example or pseudocode that is more than wildly high-level since this seems to be the exercise intended for you to complete.

Comment: do you have an article or hint?

Comment: Thanks! I have had this problem for about a year now! :(

Comment: You're welcome. It's tricky to answer "homework-like" questions such that it allows you to "aha, I know what to do" rather than copy-paste. Hopefully this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the default because the second if statement is inside the first. When the first test is true, the second test which nested inside the first test will be false casing the else clause to override your textArea with default text. You should do something like this

```
if (text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").contains("whats new")){
   ...       
}
else if (text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").contains("yes")) {
   ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: that makes it return "Cool!" if you type "yes" at all.

Comment: is that not want you want?

Comment: if there are other questions with an answer for yes (which there are) it always says "Cool!"

Comment: i am not understanding what you are saying. From what i posted this is what will happen. When a string contains "whats new", it will not check again for "yes". but if it does not contain "whats new", it will check for "yes". if it contains yes it will say "Cool!" but if it does not it will it will give default output. Is that your intention or did i get it wrong